# I can't log in google account with python and requests

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, google-authentication

The first method:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests as rq
r = rq.get('https://classroom.google.com/c/MjA0NDQ2NzQ2NDgz')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html.parser")
links = soup.find_all("a")

for link in links:
    print(link.get("href"))
```

output:

```
https://accounts.google.com/signin/usernamerecovery?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fclassroom.google.com%2Fc%2FMjA0NDQ2NzQ2NDgz&service=classroom&hl=tr
https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fclassroom.google.com%2Fc%2FMjA0NDQ2NzQ2NDgz&followup=https%3A%2F%2Fclassroom.google.com%2Fc%2FMjA0NDQ2NzQ2NDgz&service=classroom
https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?service=classroom&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fclassroom.google.com%2Fc%2FMjA0NDQ2NzQ2NDgz
https://www.google.com/intl/tr/about
https://accounts.google.com/TOS?loc=TR&hl=tr&privacy=true
https://accounts.google.com/TOS?loc=TR&hl=tr
http://www.google.com/support/accounts?hl=tr
```

Normally  I should have seen the "meet" links (classroom uses meet)

---

After I try this method:

```
from twill.commands import *

go('forum link')

fv("1", "mail","blabla.com")
fv("1", "password", "testpass")
```

But this didn't work. I didn't try but I think this method is for just forms.

---

Finally I try this method:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


form_data={'Email': 'myEmail@mail.com', 'Passwd': 'myPassword'}
post = "https://accounts.google.com/signin/challenge/sl/password"

with requests.Session() as s:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get("https://mail.google.com").text, features="lxml")
    for inp in soup.select("#gaia_loginform input[name]"):
        if inp["name"] not in form_data:
            form_data[inp["name"]] = inp["value"]
    s.post(post, form_data)
    html = s.get("https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox").content
```

If this method works on console, the output should be `true`, but it's `false`:

```
my_mail in s.get("https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox").text
```

Comment: If you are trying to authenticate, then you should know that Google does a bunch of checks before authentication including IP checks among others, and trying to detect if you're human. However, Google provides a way to authenticate with OAuth 2.0.

Comment: What steps have you tried to troubleshoot that last statement?

Comment: @gwideman "What steps have you tried to troubleshoot that last statement?" I try logging and log out in web browser I can't think of anything else

Comment: The last statement is an "in" statement, involving two arguments.  What do you expect their values to be? Have you inspected the two arguments to see what their values are? Which one is the one causing the "in" to produce false instead of true? Then work backwards to discover why that value is the way it is.